# 2 properties one validationMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I have a MVC form where i want the user to enter his FirstName and Surname but I just want the label to say 
`FullName : [input for First Name] [input for Surname] [Validation Message]`

It must be one validation message that validates that the First Name and the surname is filled in the [Validation Message] will only be a "*", but the validation summary must show two validation errors eg. The First Name is required and the surname is required.

I am using MVC4 with all the normal validation enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone can come up with a simpler solution, I would have a custom validation attribute and apply it to either of these properties (most likely Surname) and have it do the "required" validation for you. Then you can output one message if there is an error.